shadowsocks AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
I was trying to set up an VPN on Vultr via Shadowsocks, and trying to run Shadowsocks service manually.
I tried below in my bash:
sudo ssserver -c /etc/shadowsocks.json

It has error: AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
I am using Python 3.10.12 version
below is the ERROR:
    root@vpn-test:~# sudo ssserver -c /etc/shadowsocks.json 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ssserver", line 5, in <module>
    from shadowsocks.server import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/shadowsocks/server.py", line 27, in <module>
    from shadowsocks import shell, daemon, eventloop, tcprelay, udprelay, \
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/shadowsocks/udprelay.py", line 71, in <module>
    from shadowsocks import encrypt, eventloop, lru_cache, common, shell
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/shadowsocks/lru_cache.py", line 34, in <module>
    class LRUCache(collections.MutableMapping):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
root@vpn-test:~# 


Please don't post images of code/data/errors. You can edit your question and replace the images with properly formatted text. See: How to ask a good question

This question is similar to: ImportError: cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections'. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What is your shadowsocks version?

@FreePalestine It is 2.8.2

Version 2.8.2 is very old, it was good till python 3.9.
Please use the latest shadowsocks v5.3.3
Here is the link: https://gist.github.com/zhiguangwang/7018fbc0a38a5b663868
Hopefully your error will go away.

I tried pip install --upgrade shadowsocks, it still remains 2.8.2, how do I update to v5.5.5

I am not sure. How did install for the first time? May be try uninstalling the old version and reinstalling the newer version.

I think the link you are sharing is for Android, I am using Ubuntu on Vultr.

I have updated the ubuntu link.

It worked, Have to install shadowsocks-libev on server. do u know what's the difference with shadowsocks

Sorry brother, I am unaware.
